# How to call a model function from template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am calling my models(`Answer`) function `isupvoted` from template while iterating over all answers that are being shown on page to see if the loggedin user has liked the iterating answer. My `Answer` and `Upvote` models are as below.

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_text = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    answer_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ans_auth')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    a_pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Answer Published')
    a_modified_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Answer Modified', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text

    def isupvoted(self, request):
        counter = UpvoteAnswerMod.objects.filter(answer=self, upvote_user=request.user).count()
        print("upvote count: "+counter)
        return counter


class UpvoteAnswerMod(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    upvote_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    upvote_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Upvoted')
```

I am calling the function as below

```
{% if answer.isupvoted == 1 %}
   <a class="upvote pressed" href="#" >Downvote</a>
{% else %}
   <a class="upvote" href="#" >Upvote</a>
{% endif %}
```

But `answer.isupvoted` is not returning anything. How do I get the upvote count?

Comment: It looks like you have to use it with `@property` decorator.

Answer (score 1):

In your model, use `@property`:

```
@property
def isupvoted(self, user):
    try:
        counter = UpvoteAnswerMod.objects.filter(answer=self, 
                                                 upvote_user=user).count()
        print("upvote count: "+counter)
        return counter
    except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
        print("Not Found - {}".format(e))
        return 0
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: Now its giving `isupvoted() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'` error

Comment: I think you don't really have to pass request there, as you already have foreign key - `upvote_user=self.answer_author`

Comment: that takes away the whole purpose here, `upvote_user=self.answer_author` will always be true. I need to check if the loggedin user is the upvoter

Comment: In your template - you know the upvoting user id so you can pass it as {{ user.id }} or {{ upvoting_user_id }} based on how it structured, and then read that parameter in your property.

Comment: I'm not sure if that can work, because I believe there is no way we can pass arguments to the function in templates. But i'll try and see if that works.

Comment: Why not just use a custom template tag rather than trying to pass directly to model - so the problem is you need to find a way to provide upvoting user into model somehow, and this is not the owner of the answer. -for template tags see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: The answer model should not depend on any upvoting users - you can have a list of upvoters as ManyToMany field if you wish and then you don't have to pass anything to the property.